# Run time typed / Generic variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, dynamic

I'm looking way to implement class similar to following, contain a constructor with two parameters, the second parameter is a Generic runtime typed.

I'm using.Net3.5 inside Unity 3D

```
public class Parameter
{
    private mParameterName;
    private T parameterValue; // runtime parameter

    public Parameter( string parameterName, string parameterValue ){}
    public Parameter( string parameterName, long parameterValue ){}
    public Parameter( string parameterName, double parameterValue ){}
}
```

any help in correct direction will be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do:

```
public class Parameter<T>
{
    private string mParameterName;
    private T parameterValue; // runtime parameter

    public Parameter( string parameterName, T parameterValue )
    {
        this.mParameterName = parameterName;
        //this. is required below because the method parameter and class member
        //have the same name, so this. refers to the class member and without
        //refers to the method parameter.
        this.parameterValue = parameterValue;
    }
}
```

Here you define the generic type argument in the class name: `public class Parameter<T>`, and then you can use it in the constructor. You don't need a new constructor for each type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to force T to be only String, Int and and float? only in the compile time?

Comment: @Yasantha No, you can restrict it to structs (value types) or reference types, but there isn't a way to restrict it to a list of specific types.

Comment: You can restrict it to *interfaces or non-sealed classes.*

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you must precise what is the type `T` in the class as follows

```
public class Parameter<T>
{
    private string mParameterName;
    private T parameterValue; // runtime parameter

    public Parameter( string parameterName, T parameterValue ){}
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KSPxsC)